# How do I just display a photo without exposure details on my Canon Rebel T5?

Tags: canon, camera-settings

I have a Canon Rebel T5. On the display screen it has the picture and the exposure settings for the picture. I just want the picture displayed. How do I change that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to viewing a photo you have already taken (Image Playback), then refer to p.80 of the [Canon Rebel T5 Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0300014592/01/eos-rebelt5-1200d-im-en.pdf#page=134):

After you press the Image Playback button (▶️), press the <DISP> button to cycle through the display format modes:

[image]

More detailed Image Playback features are described starting on p.203.